# Monad Transformer stack receives Non-type variable argument error

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

I've started learning about monad transformers stacks using the paper [monad-transformers: Step by step](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/scravy/realworldhaskell/materialien/monad-transformers-step-by-step.pdf).
Some of the code is a bit dated but after some slight modifications, I've made it work.
But now I've stumbled upon an error message I don't fully understand.

[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgFZN.png)

As I currently understand it, m :: * -> * is of a higher kind
and the compiler wants it to be a variable i.e. m :: *.
But I don't know how I need to edit my code to make that work.

```
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.Fail
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Name = String -- variable names
data Exp = Lit Integer -- expressions
         | Var Name
         | Plus Exp Exp
         | Abs Name Exp
         | App Exp Exp
         deriving (Show )

data Value = IntVal Integer -- values
           | FunVal Env Name Exp
           deriving (Show )
type Env = Map.Map Name Value -- mapping from names to values

type Eval3 α = ReaderT Env (ErrorT String Identity) α

runEval3 :: Env -> Eval3 α -> Either String α
runEval3 env ev = runIdentity (runErrorT (runReaderT ev env ))


evel3 :: Exp -> Eval3 Value
evel3 (Lit i)= return $ IntVal i
eval3 (Var n) = do env <- ask
                   case Map.lookup n env of
                     Nothing -> throwError ("unbound variable: " ++ n)
                     Just val -> return val
eval3 (Plus e1 e2 ) = do e1' <- eval3 e1
                         e2' <- eval3 e2
                         case (e1' , e2') of
                            (IntVal i1 , IntVal i2 ) -> return $ IntVal (i1 + i2 )
                            _ ->throwError "type error in addition"
eval3 (Abs n e) = do env <- ask
                     return $ FunVal env n e
eval3 (App e1 e2 ) = do val1 <- eval3 e1
                        val2 <- eval3 e2
                        case val1 of
                          FunVal env' n body -> local (const (Map.insert n val2 env')) (eval3 body)
                          _ -> throwError "type error in application"
```

Comment: It's very important to copy and paste the error message into your question. *Do not* include it as an image. Images of text are inaccessible to visually impaired people, they can't be indexed by search engines, and they're a pain for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in your code, you wrote `evel3` instead of `eval3` in some places:

```
evel3 :: Exp -> Eval3 Value
evel3 ... = ...
eval3 ... = ...
```

This leads GHC to believe that these are two different definitions

```
-- One definition
evel3 :: Exp -> Eval3 Value
evel3 ...  = ...

-- Another definition, without a signature
eval3 ... = ...
```

GHC rejects the inferred type for `eval3`, which is much more general than `Exp -> Eval3 Value`, because it does not conform to the standard, as chi explained.

Answer (score 1):

By default, GHC uses the basic Haskell language, as it is defined in the 2010 Haskell Report.

Most modern Haskell code does not fit within that standard, but exploits several extensions.

In this case, you need to enable the `FlexibleContexts` extension, as GHC suggests in the error message.
Add this line at the very top of your code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```

Indeed, it is very customary to enable several extensions in modern Haskell. Arguably, many of them should be enabled by default.